# How to pass HashMap value without using intent?

Tags: android, google-maps

Every 3 seconds, I am receiving text messages containing latitude and longitude. To send the coordinates from my SmsReceiver.class to my MapActivity.class, I used intent, which causes my Google Map to refresh every time I receive the coordinates. Every time I receive a message, it intents another MapActivity.class. How do I pass HashMap values without using intent?

This is how I save my HashMap values which is stored on my SMSReceiver.class.

```
private HashMap<String, Double> coordinates = new HashMap<String, Double>();
 DatabaseReference mRef = databaseLocation.push();
            double latitudedb = Double.parseDouble(separatedSMS[1]);
            double longitudedb = Double.parseDouble(separatedSMS[3]);
coordinates.put("latitude", latitudedb);
        coordinates.put("longitude", longitudedb);
```

I wanted to get the HashMap values to my MapActivity.class so I would be able to place a marker on my map which positions to actual coordinates I am receiving.

Comment: you can use `broadCast `

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class and static value for this  :

```
public class CommunActivit {

private static HashMap<String, Float> ListOf;


static {
    ListOf = new HashMap<>();
}



  public static HashMap<String, Float> getListOf() {
    return ListOf;
}

public static void setListOf(HashMap<String, Float> listOf) {
    ListOf = listOf;
}
```

}

Create an instance of CommunActivit in your activity
By exemple :

```
CommunActivit obj = new CommunActivit();
```

When you get your coordinates, you can simply call the `obj.setListOf(yourhashmap)` and when you want to get it, simply call `yourhashmap = obj.getListOf();`

I use this in my app and it works fine.